# How to return measurement probabilities from the QDK Full-state simulator?

Tags: q#

Is there a way for the QDK full-state simulator to return the wavefunction or the measurement probabilities of a quantum state? Specifically to a C# host application?

I want to sample from the output distribution of a quantum algorithm in C#. Currently I am re-invoking the simulator and performing the destructive measurement for each sample, however this process is quite slow.

Comment: I think EstimateFreqency does something similar to what you're looking for, but I'm not familiar with it enough to offer a full answer. Looking at the source of its implementation at https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumLibraries/blob/b802b254b7cb98049573a367ed399e23ad784e59/Standard/src/Characterization/EstimateFrequency.cs or its uses in libraries might give you some information

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for your question! Depending a bit on the details of what you'd like to do, there's a few different options available in Q# to help you out. First and foremost, the [`DumpMachine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.diagnostics.dumpmachine) and [`DumpRegister`](https://learn.microsoft.com/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.diagnostics.dumpregister) callables instruct the simulator to dump the quantum state of either the entire machine or a particular register out to the host program. On target machines that don't support `DumpMachine` and `DumpRegister`, those calls can be safely ignored as they have no effect on the execution of a Q# program itself.

By default, the state dumped by these diagnostics either gets printed to the console when writing Q# standalone programs at the command-line, or shown as a table in Q# Notebooks. You can try out the "Dumping states and operations" sample online at http://aka.ms/try-qsharp to see a bit more detail as to how that works.

[image]

While printing out to the console or notebook is the default, you can also capture the state of the `QuantumSimulator` target machine using a C# host. While that's currently not documented terribly well (sorry about that), you can see some examples of the `QuantumSimulator.StateDumper` class being used to capture quantum states yielded by `DumpMachine` and `DumpRegister` in [IQ#](https://github.com/microsoft/iqsharp/blob/main/src/Jupyter/Visualization/StateDisplayOperations.cs#L21) and in the [Q# standard libraries](https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumLibraries/blob/main/Standard/src/Diagnostics/Emulation/Internal.cs#L17). If there's a usecase that you'd be interested in along these lines, that could be a great feature request to the [qsharp-runtime repo](https://github.com/microsoft/qsharp-runtime).

On the other hand, if you're looking to sample from output distributions from *within* Q# programs without having to repeatedly simulate destructive measurements, that is a bit more subtle. Getting measurement probabilities out without measuring can't be done on hardware, so there's no Q# intrinsic that allows for that, but some operations in the Q# standard library can use the information stored in a simulator to run significantly faster. In particular, the [`EstimateFrequencyA` operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.characterization.estimatefrequencya) can be used to efficiently estimate the frequency with which a `Zero` result is obtained from a given measurement and state preparation procedure:

```
let freq = EstimateFrequencyA(
    ApplyToFirstQubitCA(H, _), // Prepare |+⟩ on the first qubit.
    Measure([PauliZ], _),      // Measure a single qubit in the -basis.
    1,                         // Use a single qubit.
    1000000                    // Measure 1M times.
);
// freq should now be close to 0.5.
```

[image]

This works because on targets that don't allow for looking at quantum states directly, you can always get the same answer by running a loop over many destructive measurements, exactly as you pointed out in your original question. The only difference between what `EstimateFrequencyA` does on a simulator that supports "cheating" and what it does when run on a target that doesn't is performance.